# BCP - Exported files (docx, xlsx & pptx) are corrupted

Tags: sql, filestream, bcp

I am using the below bcp command to export the binary files from the filestream db and all other files are seems to be exported fine (i.e. txt, pdf, rtf, image files & etc) except docx, xlsx & pptx files. I am able to export these files (i.e. docx, xlsx & pptx) but I am getting a warning/error message when opening those files and then it opens the file properly.

```
BCP "SELECT content FROM [dbo].[Contents] WHERE ID=1" queryout "C:\Temp\" -T -S (local) -f C:\Temp\files.fmt
```

I am getting the below message when opening docx, xlsx & pptx files:

XLSX - Excel found unreadable content and Do you want to recover the contents of this document?
DOCX - The file test.docx cannot be opened bcos there are problems with the content and then Excel found unreadable content and Do you want to recover the contents of this document?

Also, I have this in my files.fmt file:

10.0 
1 
1       SQLBINARY             0       0       "\t"     1     content      ""

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe tabs or newlines were appended as col and row terminators? Not sure bcp can export a single blob.

Comment: Can you please explain me?

Comment: Do you know what bcp does and how it is typically used? It usually copies multiple columns and multiple rows. They are delimited.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure if your problem was the same as what I have had but in my case, I found that the problem was actually in the *writing* part, not in the reading part. For example, my original writing code was like this:

```
Dim FILE_CONTENT(len) As Byte
File.InputStream.Read(FILE_CONTENT, 0, len)
SaveFileToDatabase(FILE_NAME, CONTENT_TYPE, FILE_CONTENT)
```

When I changed the first line as the following :

```
Dim FILE_CONTENT(0 To len - 1) As Byte
```

the reading error disappeared. I just forgot that VB actually allocates N+1 bytes (O to N) by default when you dimension it without specifying the lower bound. See similar situation described here: [Uploaded Docx Files are getting corrupted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19406990/uploaded-docx-files-are-getting-corrupted) . hope that helps.